# how to correctly use promises to return 2 different results

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am trying to use Promises in JavaScript using ES6 to return data from 2 methods from an object, which would in production call out to an endpoint.

My `MovieApi` object I have 2 promises which I want to return firstly a list of movies, and then 1 movie by id. I want to use promises to avoid callback hell. I am following the approach listed as the answer to the question [Arent promises just callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks) but I am clearly doing it wrong, as I have the error `findMovie is not defined`

```
let movieData = [ 
    {
      id: '1011',
      name: 'Gleaming the cube', 
      year: "1989"
    },
    {
      id: "1012",
      name: "Airborne", 
      year: "1989"
    }
  ]

let MovieApi = {    
  findMovie: function(id) {    
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      if(id === undefined) reject(Error('incorrect movie id'));

      let movie = ''
      for (let m of movieData) {
        if (m.id.toLowerCase() === id.toLowerCase()) {
          movie = m
          break
        }
      }
      resolve(movie)
    });
  },
  findAllMovies: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {    
      if(movieData === undefined) reject(Error('Could not find any movies'))

      resolve(movieData)
    });
  }    
}
```

Call the movie promise like this... but I get an error trying to call my second `.then()` method

```
MovieApi.findAllMovies()
.then( function (movies){
  return findMovie(req.params.id)
}).then(function(movie){
  let MovieStore = { movie: movie, movies: movies }
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error("Failed!", error);
});
```

Is there a way to get out of callback hell here, or will I just have to make another call to the MovieApi object, essentially having the same readability issue as if I were  using callbacks.

Comment: [This is a pretty good read](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) if you want to gain a better understanding of Promises.

Comment: You surely wanted to use `MovieApi.findMovie(…)`

Comment: Well... I can see this error now, but it was a problem I was having with using promises, and now I have been helped with it, by Arun below. Thank you for linking to that similar question, it was the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `return findMovie(req.params.id)`, your `findMovie` is a property of the `MovieApi` object so

```
MovieApi.findAllMovies()
.then( function (movies){
  return MovieApi.findMovie(req.params.id)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/66dd1rpb/)

Comment: Thanks for that, so I was simply missing the MovieApi object. I am wondering what the best approach is in this case for setting up my MovieStore object which needs both movies and movie. Should I just set my MovieStore object before the promise is called, and first add the movies to it, and then the movie to it?